# Convert an Image object To FormFile object

Tags: java, image, forms, struts

It's possible to convert an  Image object To FormFile object ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to the Apache Struts [`FormFile`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/api/org/apache/struts/upload/FormFile.html)? If so, then you'd probably want to be creating a [`CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.CommonsFormFile`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/api/org/apache/struts/upload/CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.CommonsFormFile.html) which simply wraps an implementation of the [`FileItem`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html) interface, the only one of which I could find (that isn't deprecated) is a [`DiskFileItem`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItem.html). But this is for content that's been received within a multipart/form-data POST request, and not something that I would have thought you'd have an `Image` object for. Which makes me wonder what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

***update:***

Based on your feedback I would imagine you could create a `BufferedImage` object based on the `FileItem`, which should then be able to be manipulated:

```
InputStream is = fileItem.getInputStream();
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
```

Once you're happy with the BufferedImage that you've tweaked you can write it to the file system using `ImageIO.write()`.

Comment: I have a formFile i upload a file into my server but i want resize this FormFile before.

Comment: so you're uploading an image and you want it resized automatically before it is stored on disk?